# SQL Server: Programmatically Execute Maintenance Plan

Tags: sql-server, service, maintenance-plan

Is there any way to programmatically execute (start) a SQL Server maintenance plan? We have a windows service that runs nightly and updates the DB with lots of data, once that is finished we would like to trigger a maintenance plan in the DB to start running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can start a job which is part of your maintenance plan by [sp_start_job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx):

```
use msdb; 
go
exec dbo.sp_start_job N'job_name' ;
go
```

Answer (score 7):

If you get the error "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.sp_start_job'." try this one:

```
execute msdb.dbo.sp_maintplan_start @plan_id = N'549EDF1B-5712-472E-9722-DD81F622A3C2'
```

You get the guid from this query:

```
SELECT s.id AS [ID]    
FROM msdb.dbo.sysmaintplan_plans AS s    
WHERE s.name=N'MyMaintenancePlan'
```